# Search Results for Difference between androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity and android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity

Tags: android, gradle, android-appcompat, appcompatactivity

### What is the difference between the `AppCompatActivity` in the `android.support.v7.app` package and the `androidx.appcompat.app` package?

Why does it shows error on
`import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity`, can't resolve v7. Currently I'm using compileSdkVersion 29.
I have even updated the **build.gradle** file with
`implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'`

Comment: have you tried migrating to AndroidX.

Comment: Actually, I'm using androidX. So, should I use androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity or android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity, because androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity works perfectly fine for me. So, I wanted to know the difference between both of them. Which one should I use and why?

Comment: okay I'll give an answer below ASAP

Answer (score 0):

This is because of the bug that was in prior Android Studio 4.x +, its due to the wrong import of the library(android.support.v7.app.AppCompat) when you have migrated to androidx, there are two solutions

**Permanent Solution**

1. Upgrade the Android Studio to the latest version and remove the import **`AppCompatActivity`** from that activity and reimport the library using **ALT** + **ENTER**

**Solution for current project**

2. remove the import **`AppCompatActivity`**  from that activity and reimport the library using **ALT** + **ENTER**

**Which one to chose**
As a matter of fact **android.support.v7.app.AppCompat** is old and google is dropping the support in the future and is no longer maintained, on the other hand, AndroidX is recommended, androidX has more up to date libraries but has been unstable few times, in future, it will have support to more libraries which will not be supported by the **android.support.v7.app.AppCompat**, AndoirdX provide backward compatibility across Android releases. and that's why you should use AndroidX

Answer (score -1):

I think with `compileSdkVersion 29` and `targetSdkVersion 29` you only need to use

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
```

Comment: use it instead of `implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'` and in your `Activity` you will import  `androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity` .

Answer (score -1):

You should use the `import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity` and here is why from the [Android Docs](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/packages).

> We recommend using the androidx libraries in all new projects. You should also consider migrating existing projects to ensure they continue to receive bug fixes and other library improvements.

Essentially, use the `androidx` package because it receives stable update and they comprise jetpack libraries which ease up development with compatibility and some other perks.

Comment: This answer contradicts itself